# Unable to manually change slides in ionic5 app using slideNext and slideTo

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides

I built an ionic5 application that utilizes a loop to add ion-slides whose content are different radio groups whose contents are pulled from an array. My problem is when I try to use slideNext or slideTo to switch slides, it fails to work. I can only get it to work after refreshing the browser and doesnt work at all when I build an android app and test.

The code I am trying is:

```
  <ion-slides #quizSlider>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions;let i = index">
            <ion-list lines="none">   
                    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="singleanswer">
                      <ion-item *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
                          <ion-label>{{answer}}</ion-label>
                          <ion-radio slot="start" value="{{answer}}">
                          </ion-radio>
                      </ion-item>
                    </ion-radio-group>                              
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" >
                    <ion-button color="primary" (click)="checkUserAnswers(i)">Check</ion-button>
                </div> 
            </ion-list>             
      </ion-slide>    
  </ion-slides>
```

And .ts code:

```
  import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
  
  @ViewChild('quizSlider') quizSlider: IonSlides;
  
  
  export class Quiz {
  
  questions: Question[];
  
  constructor() {}
  
      checkUserAnswers(questionNo)
      {
            if(this.questions.length == questionNo + 1)
            {
                this.router.navigate(['complete']);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('test');
                //this.quizSlider.slideNext();
                //this.quizSlider.lockSwipes(false);

                this.quizSlider.slideNext();

                //this.quizSlider.lockSwipes(true);
                //let currentIndex = this.quizSlider.getActiveIndex().then( (val) => console.log(val) );
                //console.log('Current Slide: ' + currentIndex);
                //this.quizSlider.slideTo(questionNo + 1);
            }                   
      }
  
  }
```

Not sure if its related but the ionic environment I am using is:

```
  Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8 
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.5
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.900.7
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.0.7
  @angular/cli                  : 9.0.7
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0
```

**UPDATE**
I have attempted using swipe and I realized that (like the case of using button event) the slide change only works after the page is refreshed. I have tried downgrading to ionic4 but the problem has persisted